# How to find out gate number for bus at Port Authority Bus Terminal?

Tags: usa, public-transport, buses, new-york-city, greyhound

I'm traveling on Greyhound from New York City to Mount Laurel, NJ. This is my first time, so I'm a bit nervous. On my ticket, it says that to check the gate number at the Port Authority Bus Terminal, so I just wanted to ask where I would check. Should I just ask someone or is there a specific area where I should go? Also, would I go to get my baggage checked first (I'm traveling with just my backpack)? (I know I'm super confused...)

Comment: Which bus line is it?

Comment: It's Greyhound..

Comment: Greyhound - Greyhound or Greyhound sharing with some other bus line?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just  greyhound

Comment: Be sure to leave enough time at the PA to check out the "42nd Street Ballroom" sculpture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Port Authority there are multiple places where information about buses is available.

1. There are information booths at the entrance to the terminal in both buildings.
2. There are electronic screens where you can look up information.  They are now everywhere.

But if you're looking for Greyhound bus lines (not Peter Pan, not Pine Hill, or any other) you need to go to the 42nd Street building on 8th avenue and Greyhound is located downstairs. in the basement.  Once you get there there is Greyhound personnel and screens available for the information about where a particular bus is departing from.

You may be able to find more info on [Port Authority of New York/New Jersey](http://www.panynj.gov/bus-terminals/port-authority-bus-terminal.html) site.

Comment: Thank you so much! And you need to get all baggage checked first before you go the gate right?

Comment: Once you get to Greyhound area they will tell you.